# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_7_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

```
**import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
xy = np.loadtxt('../data-01-test-score.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
x_data = xy[:, 0:-1]
y_data = xy[:, [-1]]
# Make sure the shape and data are OK
print(x_data, "\nx_data shape:", x_data.shape)
print(y_data, "\ny_data shape:", y_data.shape)
# data output
'''
[[ 73.  80.  75.]
 [ 93.  88.  93.]
 ...
 [ 76.  83.  71.]
 [ 96.  93.  95.]] 
x_data shape: (25, 3)
[[152.]
 [185.]
 ...
 [149.]
 [192.]] 
y_data shape: (25, 1)
'''
tf.model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# activation function doesn't have to be added as a separate layer. Add it as an argument of Dense() layer
tf.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_dim=3, activation='linear'))
# tf.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('linear'))
tf.model.summary()
tf.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-5))
history = tf.model.fit(x_data, y_data, epochs=2000)
# Ask my score
print("Your score will be ", tf.model.predict([[100, 70, 101]]))
print("Other scores will be ", tf.model.predict([[60, 70, 110], [90, 100, 80]]))**
```

In this code, the part "print ("Your score will be", tf.model.predict ([100, 70, 101])" is incorrect. The input shape should come in (3,) but it came in (1,), so there was an error. I think it's right because input_dim is 3 and units is 1, but where is wrong?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. But you mention: "In this code, the part "print ("Your score will be", tf.model.predict ([100, 70, 101])" is incorrect." `tf.model.predict ([100, 70, 101])` this shape would be incorrect, but you seem to haved fixed it in your code example. Oh and I would recommend renaming your `tf.model` to `tf_model`

Comment: Thank you. I solved it.However, it can be done once and should not be implemented again.